# Galois group of $f(x) = x^4 + px + p$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

> Let $f(x)=x^4 + px +p \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ for prime $p$. Then, we can see $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. 
>   Then, show that
>
> (1) for $p \neq 3, 5$ , Galois group is $S_4$.
>
> (2) for $p = 3 $ , Galois group is $D_8$ (Dihedral group of order $8$)
>
> (3) for $p = 5 $ , Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (cyclic of oder $4$)

---

[My attempt]

First, the resolvent cubic of $f(x)$ is $h(y) = y^3 - 4py + p^2$. Also, the discriminant $D$ of $h(y) = -27(p^2)^2 - 4(-4p)^3 = 256p^3 - 27p^4$ and $\sqrt{D}\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

(1) When $p \neq 3, 5$ , we can know $h(y)$ is irreducible, so Galois group is $S_4$ by order argument.

(2),(3) My question is here. Since $D_8 \cap A_4$ is transitive subgroup of $S_4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4 \cap A_4$ is not , if $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ then galois is $D_8$ and if $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ then galois is $\mathbb{Z}_4$. 
 In the case (2) (that is , $p = 3$) , $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{21})$ , i have to know that $f(x)$ is irreducible or not over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{21})$. However, i don't know whether $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{q})$ is U.F.D or not ,where $q$ is prime (to use gauss lemma and eisenstein's criterion).

Similary, in the case (3) ( $p = 5$ ) , $f(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ but i don't know how can i find this fact.

[My question]

(i) How can I test irreducibility of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$.

(ii) If exsist, is there another method to solve this problem?

Thank you for your attention!

​

Comment: But $\Bbb Z_4$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_4$

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38467/standard-ways-of-telling-if-an-irreducible-quartic-polynomial-has-galois-group?rq=1), for example. Also the answers to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3180583/efficiently-calculating-the-galois-group-of-px-x44x2-2/3180671) are helpful. Furthermore, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799031/galois-group-of-irreducible-quartic-polynomial-over-mathbbq?rq=1).

Comment: @Kenny Lau thank you, i fixed it !

Comment: @Dietrich Burde , thank you so much.. but there is no answer on your links.

Comment: On the contrary, the answers and posts explain exactly in which cases we have Galois group $S_4,D_8$ or $C_4$.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde, I already know that argument but there is no answer how to determine between $D_8$ and $C4$. (In this point, my question (i) is need)